# Problem populating the ViewBag using TempData & Redirect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've inherited an MVC project and I'm having some trouble as I am very new to MVC and web development in general.

The project contains a Controller Action method which generates a view.  This method can either be called when the user accesses the view directly via the UI, or to regenerate the view after the user has clicked a button on the view to perform an action.  If the view is regenerated after an action is performed, a verification message needs to appear on the page.

In the cshtml file, we have the following in MainWindow.cshtml, which only renders the table in the conditional if a string named "SavedMessage" exists in the ViewBag and is not null or empty:

```
@{ string actionResult = ViewBag.SavedMessage; }
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionResult))
{
    <tr>
         <td>
             @actionResult
         </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In the Action method, I'm attempting to use the TempData object to transfer the string value to the Action which generates the view:

```
public partial class ApproveController : Controller
{
    const string IDX_ACTIONRESULT = @"ActionResult";

    public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection collection)
     {
         try
         {
             string result_success = @"Action completed successfully";
             //Do stuff
             TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] = result_success;
             return RedirectToAction("MainWindow");
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Logger.reportException(e);
             throw e;
         }
     }
 }
```

In the Action which generates the view, we load the value stored in TempData into a variable, and then test to see if the variable contains anything.  If the variable is not null, I am attempting to load whatever it contains into the ViewBag.

Create View Action:

```
public partial class ApproveController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MainWindow()
    {
        //Do Stuff
        var actionResult = TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT];
        if (actionResult != null)
        {
            Log.info("Action Result Message: " + actionResult);
            ViewBag.SavedMessage = actionResult;  
        }
        else
            Log.info("Action Result Message is NULL");


        return View();
    }
}
```

**Possible lead:** 
When the MainWindow() method is called through UI rather than Redirect from MyAction(), my log indicates that actionResult is **null**, however, when it is called via Redirect from MyAction(), actionResult is an **empty string**. This leads me to believe that MyAction() is populating TempData with *something* but I can't see why it doesn't contain the string I'm assigning in MyAction().

Anyone see a smoking gun here?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @Jasen - I need the string I'm adding to TempData in MyAction() to persist when MyAction() redirects to MainWindow() so that I can add it to the ViewBag.

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but in your view you are checking `savedMessage` rather than `actionResult`. Have you debugged the controller and verified that `TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT]` is indeed an empty string?

Comment: @Jasen - Thanks for the catch; I've fixed this.  This is a typo introduced while obfuscating my code; the real code is accurate.  as to your second question, I'm fairly certain that TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] is an empty string when we redirect from MyAction.  When we generate the view from the UI, TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] is definitely NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use a combination of TempData and the ViewBag to accomplish my goal.  Here's what I did:

**Worker Action**
Here, we just assign a string value to TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] based on whether or not the action succeeds.  Instead of throwing the exception, we'll log the exception and then report failure using this TempData attribute

```
public partial class ApproveController : Controller
{
    const string IDX_ACTIONRESULT = @"ActionResult";

    public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection collection)
     {
         try
         {
             //Do stuff
             TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] = @"Action completed successfully";
             return RedirectToAction("MainWindow");
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Logger.reportException(e);
             TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] = @"The Action failed. Please contact your system administrator for assistance";
         }
     }
}
```

**Create View Action**
When we build the view, we'll check to see if the attribute TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] has an assigned value.  If so, we'll read that value and assign it to ViewBag.SavedMessage.

```
public partial class ApproveController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MainWindow()
    {   
        if (TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT] != null)
            ViewBag.SavedMessage = TempData[IDX_ACTIONRESULT].ToString();

        //Build the rest of the view

        return View();
    }
}
```

The empty string that I referenced in the *Possible Lead* portion of my question was attributed to the previous developer's code.  He was simply reading the HTTP response message from a RESTful API call into the return value of a method.  As it happens, that particular API returns an empty message on success.  So, it seems that I've been chasing my tail for a few days :)

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` uses Session storage to persist the data. My guess is that you haven't enabled session as it doesn't come by default any more I don't believe.

You need to add `services.AddSession();` and `app.AddSession();` to your startup code in order to enable it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#installing-and-configuring-session

Comment: Thanks.  I had a look at the article.  Although this is an MVC project, it builds as a class library rather than a web application (I have no idea why the developer chose to do it that way).  I searched the project for an invocation of the ConfigureServices() method, but it's not found.

Can you recommend any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?  I just need a string to persist between the action and the view.  I can't believe this is so difficult...

Comment: If you just need to persist a string, you can use a hidden input and assign the value from the model/viewbag and just have it included in the post back

Comment: Thanks, but as I'm not a web developer, that means almost nothing to me. I would need to see at least a partial code sample.  I apologize if I'm coming off rude, but I've been at this for over a week and everything about web development seems to be intentionally unintuitive